# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Tags: python, hashtable, typeerror, nonetype

I have some troubles with the `Type Error (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType)`

I just want to do a little hash table with linear probing in python. Therefore I used to make an insert method, a find method and a hash method so far. I have problems with my insert method.
This is my code

```
    def insert(self, key):

        index = self.hash(key)
        count = 0
        if self.table[index] == None or self.table[index].getValue() == "DELETED":
            self.table[index] = key
            return count + 1
        else:
            inserted = False
            while inserted != True:
                index += 1
                count += 1
                if index == self.size:
                    index = 0
                if self.table[index] == None or self.table[index].getValue() == "DELETED":
                    self.table[index] = key
                    return count
```

The problem are these two lines

`if self.table[index] == None or self.table[index].getValue() == "DELETED":`

What should I do?
I need to compare my table index with None.
Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Is `self.table` a list? You can use `None` as a key for dictionaries, but it's not a valid list index.

Comment: Can you please paste your `self.hash` function here.

Comment: what is `table` ?

Comment: from my `def __init__(self, size = 11) ` method `self.table = [None] * self.size` so table is going to be my hashtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your self.hash function is returning None. Since the value of index is None it is not able to find the value in list self.table. Can you write the hash function as well?

Comment: yes, I just had a little mistake in my hash function. Thank!